# Assign tasks to worker with min cost max flow problem

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory, or-tools

I want to model an assignment problem as a min cost max problem using a network similar to the example from Google OR-Tools: "[Assignment as a min cost max flow problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/assignment_min_cost_flow)"

Here is a working example:

[image: Picture of graph]

The flow from source to tasks specify how many of the different tasks need to be done. Worker nodes represent type of workers that have skillset to perform a set of tasks.
The cost between tasks and workers are specified as priorities: which worker should preferably do which task.
One worker becomes busy when performing a task so the capacity on edges from workers to sink are constrained by how many of the different type of workers are available. In this example I have only 5 of workers w1 and 5 of workers w2.
Since there are more tasks than workers, the flow through the orange lines show which tasks are not assigned to workers.

Here is the associated code.

```python
import pandas as pd
from ortools.graph.python import min_cost_flow

def allocate_workers(df_in,node_name,supply_list):
    #df_in:dataframe with start_nodes,end_nodes,cost and capacity as strings
    #node_name: list of all nodes
    #supply_list: supply/demand for nodes.

    #Creating unique ids for each node described as string
    node_id={}
    for i in range(len(node_name)):
        node_id[node_name[i]]=i
    #And replacing
    df_temp=df_in.replace(node_id)


    smcf = min_cost_flow.SimpleMinCostFlow()
    df_temp[['cost']]=df_temp[['cost']].astype(int)
    df_temp[['capacity']]=df_temp[['capacity']].astype(int)

    
    # Add each arc.
    for row in df_temp.itertuples():
        smcf.add_arc_with_capacity_and_unit_cost(
            row.start_nodes,row.end_nodes,row.capacity,row.cost
        )
    # Add node supplies.
    for i in range(len(supply_list)):
        smcf.set_node_supply(i,supply_list[i])

    # Find the minimum cost flow 
    status = smcf.solve()
    flow=[]
    cost_flow=[]
    
    if status == smcf.OPTIMAL:
        
        for arc in range(smcf.num_arcs()):
            flow.append(smcf.flow(arc))
            cost_flow.append(smcf.unit_cost(arc)*smcf.flow(arc))

    else:
        print('There was an issue with the min cost flow input.')
        print(f'Status: {status}')

    df_out=df_in
    df_out['flow']=flow
    df_out['cost_flow']=cost_flow
    print(df_out)
    print('Total cost = ', smcf.optimal_cost())
    return df_out

#Input data
d={
    'start_nodes':['source']*3+['t1','t2','t2','t3']+['t1','t2','t3']+['w1','w2'],
    'end_nodes':['t1','t2','t3']+['w1','w1','w2','w2']+['sink']*3+['sink']*2,
    'cost':[0]*3+[1,2,3,4]+[1000]*3+[0]*2,
    'capacity':[10,5,5]+[5]*4+[5]*3+[5]*2
}

graph_df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
node_name=['source','t1','t2','t3','w1','w2','sink']
supply=[20,0,0,0,0,0,-20]

#Call function to perform assignment
graph_df=allocate_workers(graph_df,node_name,supply)

#Show results
print(graph_df)
```

My question is how to modify this to take into account that some subsets of tasks can be performed simultaneously by one worker. So for example that worker w1 can perform both t1 and t2 in paralell because this type of worker are able to do the tasks at the same time.

I thought about creating new nodes for tasks that can be done simultaneously, for example "t1+t2" that can only be connected to w1 and that have a higher priority. The problem with this solution is that somehow I must reduce the total number of tasks: for example worker 1 takes in 5 of t1 and 5 of t2 but what comes out should not be 10, but 5 because we are using 5 workers to do these 10 tasks.

Answer (score 2):

As answered the last time you asked the question. Please do not introduce any time component in the formulation. I makes no sense as nowhere you have the notion that 1 task is after another.

Is your question: worker can do more than 1 task ? then have 1 right node for each worker (instead of aggregated) and  increase the capacity of the arc out to more than 1.

But you cannot add any specifications on the task that will be done. This would add a 'choice' and would need an NP-Compete solver and not a polynomial one like min-cost-flow.

You can always expand the state/nodes in the graph. But most likely that expansion is exponential in nature (once again this is a choice part).

So your better better is to switch to a complete solver (linear solver wrapper or CP-SAT). Be aware that these solvers are order of magnitude slower than a min-cost-flow solver.

Comment: Splitting up workers as individuals and constraining the flow out of a worker to either 1 (if it can only perform one task) or 2 (it it can perform two tasks) answered my question! This way we can get an overview if only some workers of a specific category poerform two tasks. It is a bit more work to make sense of the data coming out of the solver but manageable :-).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture of the solution proposed.[image: Picture of the network]

I have also updated the code:

```python
import pandas as pd
from ortools.graph.python import min_cost_flow

def allocate_workers(df_in,node_name,supply_list):
    #df_in:dataframe with start_nodes,end_nodes,cost and capacity as strings
    #node_name: list of all nodes
    #supply_list: supply/demand for nodes.

    #Creating unique ids for each node described as string
    node_id={}
    for i in range(len(node_name)):
        node_id[node_name[i]]=i
    #And replacing
    df_temp=df_in.replace(node_id)


    smcf = min_cost_flow.SimpleMinCostFlow()
    df_temp[['cost']]=df_temp[['cost']].astype(int)
    df_temp[['capacity']]=df_temp[['capacity']].astype(int)

    
    # Add each arc.
    for row in df_temp.itertuples():
        smcf.add_arc_with_capacity_and_unit_cost(
            row.start_nodes,row.end_nodes,row.capacity,row.cost
        )
    # Add node supplies.
    for i in range(len(supply_list)):
        smcf.set_node_supply(i,supply_list[i])

    # Find the minimum cost flow 
    status = smcf.solve()
    flow=[]
    cost_flow=[]
    
    if status == smcf.OPTIMAL:
        
        for arc in range(smcf.num_arcs()):
            flow.append(smcf.flow(arc))
            cost_flow.append(smcf.unit_cost(arc)*smcf.flow(arc))

    else:
        print('There was an issue with the min cost flow input.')
        print(f'Status: {status}')

    df_out=df_in
    df_out['flow']=flow
    df_out['cost_flow']=cost_flow
    print(df_out)
    print('Total cost = ', smcf.optimal_cost())
    return df_out

#Input data
d={
    'start_nodes':['source']*3+['t1','t1','t1','t1','t1']+['t2','t2','t2','t2','t2']+['t2','t2','t2','t2','t2']+
    ['t3','t3','t3','t3','t3']+['w1,1','w1,2','w1,3','w1,4','w1,5']+['w2,1','w2,2','w2,3','w2,4','w2,5']+['t1','t2','t3'],

    'end_nodes':['t1','t2','t3']+['w1,1','w1,2','w1,3','w1,4','w1,5']+['w1,1','w1,2','w1,3','w1,4','w1,5']+['w2,1','w2,2','w2,3','w2,4','w2,5']+
    ['w2,1','w2,2','w2,3','w2,4','w2,5']+['sink']*5+['sink']*5+['sink']*3,

    'cost':[0]*3+[1]*5+[2]*5+[3]*5+[4]*5+[0]*5+[0]*5+[1000]*3,
    'capacity':[10,5,5]+[1]*5+[1]*5+[1]*5+[1]*5+[2]*5+[1]*5+[10,5,5]
}

graph_df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
node_name=['source','t1','t2','t3','w1,1','w1,2','w1,3','w1,4','w1,5','w2,1','w2,2','w2,3','w2,4','w2,5','sink']
supply=[20]+[0]*13+[-20]

#Call function to perform assignment
graph_df=allocate_workers(graph_df,node_name,supply)

#Show results
print(graph_df)
```

When running this code, the output gives you:
[image: code output]

[image: code output]

The flow from t1 to sink is 5, showing that 5 of tasks t1 could not be assigned.
The flow from w1,1, w1,2 etc is 2, showing that they took on 2 tasks.